# Observable.timer - time delay not accurate

Tags: java, android, timer, rx-java

I encounter an issue when using an Observable.timer object to produce a delay (Android platform, Java language): compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

I would like to set up an onclick listener on an activity button. When the button is pressed, it should scan beacons around it (playBeaconScan()) and then set up a timer of 20 seconds (20000 Milliseconds) to stop the process.

More precisely, this process yields two possible outcomes:

- If beacons are found before the 20 seconds delay, the listener (listenToScan) is replaced with something else -> this works fine.
- If no beacons are found after 20 seconds, Observable.timer is fired, and this stops the beacons scan process (stopBeaconScan is called).

**The issue here is that the 20 second delay is not respected. Actually, the timer event is fired *almost always before* (range is 5-20 seconds, average is 10 seconds).**

I suspect the issue is created by using Schedulers.io as execution thread, but this is the one that looks to me as the most appropriate for the use case (I am no expert on this though).

Many thanks in advance for your help with this.

Code detail below:

```
public class BeaconsScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
// ... some class fields

// listener to rescan
private View.OnClickListener listenToScan = (v-> {
    Log.d("DelayTest", "onClickBeaconScan");
    // launch scan process
    playBeaconScan();
    // Launch timer
    Observable.timer(20000 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe( l -> {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Timer finished");
                stopBeaconScan();});
});

// ... class methods ...
```

Comment: What version of rxjava are you using?

Comment: compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.20.5'

Comment: You are using a pretty old version. Please use `io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0` instead.

Comment: You solved it, thanks! 
I may delete the question as well, but I'd suggest to post that rx version should be checked as the solution, it could help others too.